# SYNTAX inside a $_POST

Tags: php, html, variables, post, checkbox

I have this code line:

```
<input  lass="validate[minCheckbox[1]] checkbox" name="samplecheckbox <?=$row_Answer['QuestionIDFK']; ?> []"  id="samplecheckbox <? = $row_Answer['QuestionIDFK']?>[]" value="<?= $row_Answer['AnswerIDPK']; ?>" type="checkbox" />
```

Where the checboxes' names are something like `samplechecbox14[],samplechebox21[]`

What is the correct php syntax for call this element inside of a `$_POST`? . I was trying with :

```
foreach(... as $QuestionIDFK){

        foreach($_POST['samplecheckbox.$QuestionIDFK.'] as $valueID){
                // Intert on tables
}}
```

or

```
    foreach(... as $QuestionIDFK){

        foreach($_POST['samplecheckbox<?= $row_Answer['QuestionIDFK']?>'] as $valueID){
                // Intert on tables
}}
```

but don't works. I need call this in that way , i know other ways but i have use this because i need a common name per question (and multiple answers per question) . So what i should to write inside POST ?

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)` would show you exactly what array keys/"path" to use. And note that your second example is trying to embed php-in-php. Nope, not gonna work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 foreach($_POST['samplecheckbox' . $QuestionIDFK] as $valueID){
```

Assuming that `$QuestionIDFK` contains the `$row_Answer['QuestionIDFK']` value you used when you built the form.